# Avoid linking after each minor change in code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Lately I've found the "Edit and continue" feature very useful. ([How does "Edit and continue" work in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224500/how-does-edit-and-continue-work-in-visual-studio))
I wonder if it was possible to do the same, but not necessarily during the execution.

The problem is that some minor changes are neccessary usually when there is some fatal error, but "Edit and Continue" doesn't work anymore since the debugging process is finished.
Linking takes some time and it would be good to avoid it after each minor change in code. If the feature works during execution, why shouldn't it work when it's stopped?

(I'm working with Visual Studio 2008)

Any ideas?

Comment: "If the feature works during execution, why shouldn't it work when it's stopped?" How can you "continue" when you're stopped?

Comment: Well I don't say it should work in the same way (It could be "edit and run immediately"). As far as I understand this feature, it somehow overrides the modified function residing in memory. My idea was to be able to do the same, but in the hard disk memory (in the bin file).

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar Enable Minimal Rebuild option that only relinks the modules actually changed.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfz8ad09(v=VS.100).aspx

Like Edit and Continue it only works when the changes are minor, so occasionally you will have to do a full rebuild anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that's also a nice feature, good to know! Still I think it's not what I meant. This feature is about recompiling (to determine if necessary or no). Total linking still seems inevitable.